# Why is not a good idea to keep a sorted list in a extremely simple restaurant simulator

Tags: python, sorting

I just begin to study python 3. There is a project about doing a simple restaurant simulator to see which four given approaches (1. Fist-in,fist-served, 2. last-in, first-served, 3. serve the most expensive order first, 4. serve the one with least preparation time first) yield the best results(profit and number of customer served)

The idea is to have a customer class and a restaurant class to assist the simulation.

The restaurant class have two main methods, add_customer(new_comer) and process(unit_time).

I wrote my codes in a way that each time when adding new customers, Ill add new_comer to a waiting_list and then sorted accordingly base on the four subclasses' approach, then use the same block of codes to process different approaches. However, my TA told me that it may not be the best way to keep a sorted.
Hence, I am wondering if there is a better or more efficient way to add and process customer without using sorted list?

Regards,
Sebastian

Comment: Are you saying you are sorting each time? I think they may say insert it in order rather than sort the whole list.

Comment: @mattsap I am sorting each time add_customer(new_comer) is being called in the simulator. However, New_comer is an instance of Customer(). those four approaches listed above have very different serving method for the people in waiting line.

Comment: The first one asks you to implement a queue, the second one asks you to implement a stack, and the third and fourth are variations of priority queue data structures.

Comment: There are many examples how to build Stack, Queue and Priority Queue on the web

Comment: @dmitryro Thank you for pointing it out. That's brilliant. But can you explain why sorted is not a good idea?

Comment: @dmitryro I do know how to build stack queue and priority queue. Thank you for point out the idea of using them.

Comment: Sorted is not a good idea because not only have you to place them in certain order, but also provide a method of getting them in and out based on the criteria, which differs in 4 cases.

Comment: @dmitryro You are awesome. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: @dmitryro if you can put it in an answer section instead of comments, I can mark yours as the desire one

Comment: You can efficiently implement all of these using the `heapq` module.

Comment: @AChampion what's heapd module?

Comment: @SebastianY. search before firing off a question. [**`heapq`**](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/heapq.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one asks you to implement a QUEUE , the second one asks you to implement a STACK, and the third and fourth are variations of PRIORITY QUEUE data structures.